# Favicon not showing on main branch index.html

Tags: html, github-pages, favicon

My project is a portfolio site hosted on GitHub Pages with all images hosted on my University server. address is säll.com

The problem I have is that in my main branch, I have an `index.html` file with this code for the favicon

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://people.kth.se/~dsall/favicon.png?"/>
```

As you can see if you go to säll.com, it's not showing up. However, on for example säll.com/alunskar I have the exact same code and it shows up.

What am I doing wrong? I tried the thing with adding a question mark, the x-ico thing.

```html
    <p><html>

<head>
         
         <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://people.kth.se/~dsall/favicon.png?"/>

</head>
<body>

<p>hey</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On SO you need to put a [mre] _in the question_, but think about the difference in _where_ that link is on different pages.

Comment: its in the head in both, the exact same place. I'll add a minimal reproducible example. Also, i tried moving the icon to the root but still the same issue

Comment: "*its in the head in both*" Not quite. Your HTML document that's being served to my browser starts with a `<p>`, which is an implicit declaration of `<body>`. Once that's interpreted in this manner, your declarations of `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, etc. are not interpreted the same way. This does not seem to be intentional, and you should likely remove that `<p>` from the beginning of the document for the remainder of your markup to work as you expect it to.

Comment: Makes sense, honestly i dont remember why the <p> was there, but i was to afraid of removing it after it being there for such a long time. Just tried it and it was solved. Thank you so much! now i have to figure out why i like a year ago put a random <p> tag over my entire file. Once again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<link rel='icon' ...>` tag appears in the `<body>` element of the linked site.

While some `<link>` tags can appear here and be considered syntactically valid, the `icon` relationship must appear in the `<head>`.

MDN has a helpful summary on [their page for `<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#try_it):

> A `<link>` element can occur either in the `<head>` or `<body>` element, depending on whether it has a link type that is [`body-ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#try_it). For example, the `stylesheet` link type is `body-ok`, and therefore `<link rel="stylesheet">` is permitted in the body. However, this isn't a good practice to follow; it makes more sense to separate your `<link>` elements from your body content, putting them in the `<head>`.

See [the relevant HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok); note that `icon` is not "`body-ok`".

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand your answer. I'll look at the documentation you shared, thanks. I guess it's related to your comment about the <p> tag, making the link act as if it was in the body. I just want to say thank you so much for helping me. I't really means alot that you take the time to answer a novice like me. Also going out of your way to go to my site and inspect the code. It really means a lot and I've been scratching my head on that for a while.